Making a terminal-slide-up effect in python
I'm working on a project where i need a transition effect when needed. I'm running this python project through 'cool-retro-term' a CRT terminal emulator.
I want to make it like the old-school CRT terminal's where the screen smoothly slides up all characters to present the next line or to refresh the screen.
Like this:
Terminal Slide Effect
NOT THE CHARACTERS BEING PRINTED INDIVIDUALLY, BUT THE SCROLLING OF THE SCREEN.
So far the best I've done is create a function with a bunch of empty prints in a loop:
import time

def slide_up():
    for _ in range(30):
        print("")
        time.sleep(0.03)
    clear()

The clear() is a function that clears the terminal screen:
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
If anyone knows how I could accomplish this effect I'd greatly appreciate it.

To directly control the screen scrolling, you need something like VT100 control codes. Try this demo. It uses different VT100 control codes to hide/show the cursor and scroll up/down.
import time

def smooth_scroll(lines=10, delay=0.1):
    """
    Smoothly scrolls the terminal up or down a specified number of lines with a delay using VT100 escape codes.

    Args:
    lines (int): The number of lines to scroll. Positive values scroll up, negative values scroll down.
    delay (float): The delay in seconds between each line scroll.
    """
    print("\033[?25l", end="", flush=True)  # Hide the cursor
    
    if lines > 0:
        for _ in range(lines):
            print("\033[1S", end="", flush=True)  # Scroll up one line
            time.sleep(delay)
    else:
        for _ in range(abs(lines)):
            print("\033[1T", end="", flush=True)  # Scroll down one line
            time.sleep(delay)
            
    print("\033[?25h", end="", flush=True)  # Show the cursor

# Example usage
smooth_scroll(lines=20, delay=0.2)  # Scrolls up 20 lines
smooth_scroll(lines=-10, delay=0.2)  # Scrolls down 10 lines

You have to be using a terminal that supports VT100 control codes.

Your code is correct, except for one thing: you need to add flush=True to your print calls. Also, you don’t need to have empty strings in the print calls, print() works with no args. I have added some convenient arguments for more customisation, but they all have default values so you can call it with no arguments. I also made it smooth scroll the entire length of the display with os.get_terminal_size. Documentation here.
from time import sleep
from os import system, get_terminal_size

clear = lambda: system('clear')

def slide_up(n:int=get_terminal_size().lines, sleep_: float=0.05):
    for _ in range(n):
        print("")
        sleep(sleep_)
    clear()

If you don’t put flush=True in, on some systems (or even just sometimes) it won’t do the effect you’re talking about.
Or you could use curses, but that tends to over-complicate things.

Terminal emulators scroll text automatically as you print newlines. Maybe try something like this?
import time

def smooth_print(text, delay=0.1):
    """Prints the given text smoothly, character by character, with a specified delay.

    Args:
        text (str): The text to print.
        delay (float): The delay in seconds between each character.
    """
    for char in text + "\n":  # Manually add newline because is set to ""
        print(char, end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(delay)

smooth_print("Hello, world!", 0.1)  # Example


thanks but, i more meant how the terminal slides up as shown in the .gif
but thanks on the characters sliding across the screen.

It should be enough to use flush=True as people have said, but I think you would enjoy the bext library for "cool" printing and scrolling effects.
For example you can use this snippet to print text from bottom up, giving a nice old school scrolling vibe:
    import bext
    import time

    x, y = bext.size()

    bext.clear()

    text = '''
    I'm working on a project
    where i need a transition
    effect when needed.
    I'm running this python project
    through 'cool-retro-term' a CRT terminal em
    '''

    text = text.splitlines()
    length = len(text)

    for i in range(y):
            bext.goto(0,y-i-1)
            print(text[-(i%length)])
            time.sleep(0.4)

